What sequence does Hibernate use if no valid one is specified für @GeneratedValue?
I have an @Entity that uses the @GeneratedValue annotation to generate IDs like this:
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_entity_table")
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_sequence")
  private Long id;

}

No @SequenceGenerator was specified and no sequence with the name my_sequence actually exists in the database. Hibernate never complained though and entities could successfully be persisted and apparently some sequence is used.
Now I want to find out which sequence is actually used, but don't know how.
It is NOT hibernate_sequence (which I assume should have been the default). If I execute select currval('hibernate_sequence'); I get a number which is way higher then the one that has been used in my_entity_table.
It is also none of the other sequences that exists in my DB.
select pg_get_serial_sequence('my_entity_table', 'id'); returns null.
I don't have any sequence specific properties configured (like spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings).
Is there some other default sequence?
I'm using Hibernate 5.6.10 and Postgres 13.15.

I remembered to activate Hibernate logging which revealed the name of the used sequence.
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

I then noticed that I wasn't right when I stated the used sequence wasn't one of the other sequences I have in my DB. I must have missed it when I checked their current values.
I still don't understand completely why this specific sequence was used. I assume it was due to the misconfigured @Entity without @SequenceGenerator and the fact that multiple other entities redefine a generator with the same name.
